# Removing an item from content type won't remove it's propertys

Tags: content-type, managed-property, crawled-property

Whenever I remove a column in the Content Type, i still see the crawled propertys of that column when i try to do the mapping in the Manage Propertys. How can I definetely remove a column in the content type, so it "won't stay there".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure they are unmapped and then you can delete the unmapped properties
http://sharepointbrainpump.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-delete-a-crawled-property.html

There are as well some cmdlets that may help
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/remove-spenterprisesearchcrawlmapping?view=sharepoint-ps